# std::cin error state and variable changing

Tags: c++, iostream, cin

I thought that, if `cin` enters an error state, the variable it is streaming into remains unchanged.  However, the following seems to be a counterexample:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Enter int: ";

  int i = 5;
  cin >> i;

  if(cin.fail()) cout << "failed \n";
  cout << "You entered: " << i << "\n";
}
```

Running:

```
Enter int: g
failed 
You entered: 0
```

Where did I go oh so wrong?

Comment: This code worked perfectly fine with me.. with output as 5! (MSVC)

Comment: the datatype for i was int; you have given a char value at output..

Comment: AFAIK this comes under the regime of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour has changed in C++11. Failed integer extraction now sets the variable to 0.

GCC 4.8 exhibits the new behaviour even without `-std=c++11` flag, which is probably a bug/limitation of the library. There's only one libstdc++, and it doesn't know which compiler flags were used to compile `main`.

Comment: Do you know how I can see which version of C++ I'm using?  I'm using g++ and in order to use other C++0x (same as C++11 I've heard?) features I've had to add -std=c++0x when compiling, so I'm not sure which one I used here.   EDIT:  Using g++ 4.6.3

Comment: You should not rely on either behaviour anyway. Treat the value as indeterminate.

Comment: Yes, c++0x is the same as c++11, so you are using C++11.